# Pyramiding creates completely independent orders

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to work a strategy that uses pyramiding to average down in a losing long position. It works but it creates 2 separate orders. Take a look below. Note the exit times, both orders are exited at the same time and price.

[image: TV screenshot]

This gives me very incorrect performance numbers. Instead of 2 orders of outcomes -1.51% and 4.41%, it should be 1 order of 2.9%.

I'm using `strategy.entry('buy', true)` to create buy orders. Please do not ask for my full code, everything works perfectly, I just need these two orders to be combined in one.

Answer (score 0):

The broker emulator creates one exit for each position you entered. If you entered twice, as is shown in your screenshot, then you will get two exits.

Comment: Yeah but that's not right, is it? The metrics are way off. 1 trade with 2 entries is not at all the same thing as 2 trades. Are you a staff member at TV?